# Entities which came from EJB modules needn't be visible on your project's classpath

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb, war

I am creating a RESTful web service from a J2EE application in netbeans. I have the EJB project and the war project. I have my entities in the EJB and I am going to create the web service in my war. Is wrong?

When I try my WS it shows me these errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity bean class: class EntityPackage.Cliente, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [EntityType] was found for the key class [EntityPackage.Cliente] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Entity] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>EntityPackage.Cliente</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
```